# Source for bfbrute?

Tags: discussion

Apologies if this isn't the right thing to post in codegolf meta, but I have no idea where else to post this.

A while back, KSab wrote a tool that brute forces Brainfuck code. I'd like to codegolf with it, but it's down.

Does someone still have it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My bad

https://github.com/ksabry/bfbrute is back up